# (React Frontend) When Data is Received from the Backend, I Can't Access the Object That's been Returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working on React and I cannot access the object that has been returned. Here's the code and this is what I mean.

```
onSubmitCreate = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/groups/create_group', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                description: this.state.description,
                members: 1,
                likes: 0
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('this is what Im working on' + data.group.name);
                if (data) {
                    //this.props.loadUser(user);
                    console.log('this is what Im working on' + data);
                    this.props.onCreateGroup(data);
                }
            });
    }
```

[image]
So as you can see the when I try to console.log (data.name) it won't let me get to the information that I need to. So I used postman to check if I'm not getting the information that I need properly, but in post man it returns properly.

[image]

but in the frontend, I just can't access the object and the information. It just says it's undefined and I don't know what's going on at all.

Please let me know if what I'm doing is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you just do `console.log(data)` chrome will let you view the object instead of just returning [object object] which may give you more insight into what is actually being received.

Comment: use ```console.log('this is what Im working on' , data)```  instead of  ```console.log('this is what Im working on' + data)``` because if u use '+' chrome will format your obj to string to concatenate text strings like  ```console.log('this is what Im working on' + data.toString())```

Comment: Can you show your `network tab` please?And in your network tab just active `XHR` and show if response is being sent by the server.If not your problem may comme from `CORS` , the security feature implemented by your `browser` that `postman` doesn't user